# wpf how to tell if a storyboard is reversed?

Tags: wpf

I know i can hook into the State Changed event and others, however what i can not figure out is how to tell if my storyboard is running in reverse. It is set to auto reverse and repeat forever, and that works well. Now I jut need a little help on how to tell which way it is playing. Many thanks.

Comment: What framework are you using? What language? We are going to need more detail.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an easy way to determine that from the Storyboard alone - I would set an either/or value like Visibility on an extra element to determine that:

- Visibility.Visible when forward
- Visibility.Collapsed when backwards